# Passing multiple model to controller and bind the data to viewpage

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how can i Pass multiple model to controller and bind the data to viewpage

i have list page in that page contains two tabs, one for active list and another one In active list.

how can i create a model and bind the data to viewpage.

how can i bind the data to view page, i used strong typed model

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SomeViewModel> Active { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SomeViewModel> InActive { get; set; }
}
```

this is my view page code

```
<% foreach (var model in Model)
   { %>
     <tr>
       <td>
          <%= Html.ActionLink(model.TITLE, "Detail", new { id = model.EVENT_ID })%>
        </td>
```

I got an error

```
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<EventListing.Models.MyViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'Active' and no extension method 'Active' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<EventListing.Models.MyViewModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:



Line 221:                    </thead>
Line 222:                    <tbody>
Line 223:                        <% foreach (var model in Model.Active)
Line 224:                           { %>
Line 225:                        <tr>
```

Comment: This question is very vague - stackoverflow wont help you learn MVC, but will help you solve specific problems in MVC. For learning MVC3 go [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc) and [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/03/09/free-video-training-asp-net-mvc-3-features.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a view model that contains the two lists as properties:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SomeViewModel> Active { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SomeViewModel> InActive { get; set; }
}
```

and then pass an instance of `MyViewModel` to the view from the controller action.

Comment: how can i bind the data to view page, i used strong typed model. this is my view page code          -                     <% foreach (var model in Model)
                           { %>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <%= Html.ActionLink(model.TITLE, "Detail", new { id = model.EVENT_ID })%>
                            </td>

Comment: @sathishkumar, assuming you use the model I suggested you could loop through the Active property: `<% foreach (var model in Model.Active) { %>`

Comment: i got an error i mention the error in my post. please give me a solution

Comment: @sathishkumar, the view should not use `IEnumerable<EventListing.Models.MyViewModel>` as model but `EventListing.Models.MyViewModel`.